# Can't send or swap crypto

Tags: phantom-wallet

I sent the 14,7usdt from my binance account to phantom wallet, and i have received. But now from my phantom wallet i can't swap crypto on raydium, example: usdt to sol - it just won't. it says: transaction in progress.. then i tried to send back 14,7usdt on binance account, with solana network and then says: NOT ENOUGH SOL - You don't have enough SOL in your wallet for this transaction. Please deposit more and try again!

What is problem? i can't swap and i can't send back again on binance account :(

please, help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have USDT in the wallet and no SOL, you won't be able to send transactions because you don't have any SOL to pay the transaction fee. Transfer a small amount of SOL to your wallet and then try the swap again.

Comment: yes, that was the problem.. thank you nayway :)